# if i answer my own question that I put a bounty on should I not get back my bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Say I post a question that I am looking for a solution for and one or two people answer but they do not provide enough information OR provide only partial info that does not lead to the answer, I can then put a bounty out in order to try and get an answer from the community. However, if during the bounty period, I ALSO research the question further and find a solution and I post the solution as the answer, SURELY I deserver to get the bounty returned or at least half returned right? Would you agree that this is a fairer system than the current system?

Comment: Has been extensively discussed on SO.meta. Bounty is not so much a reward, consider it the cost of advertising your question.

Comment: So it's not a way to pay for a question, but from the other side of things it is a way to *get paid* for answering a question? In that case, should Google pay me when I end up buying something from their sponsored ads? I mean, if it's for advertisement only, why is there this other side of encouraging people to answer with the reward?

Answer (score 15):

This was (kinda) possible at one point now long in the past - it ended up just being abused, and tended to result in bad blood between answerers even when used properly.

[As Sdry notes](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/472/if-i-answer-my-own-question-that-i-put-a-bounty-on-should-i-not-get-back-my-boun#comment543_472), the bounty system was intended to provide a way for folks to attract more attention to questions they felt needed it; it's *not* a way to "pay" for answers. You can offer a bounty and get no responses, offer a bounty and solve your own problem, even offer a bounty and not get an answer until after it's expired.... In no case will it be refunded. In exchange for the reputation you give up, the post is highlighted for a period of time - whether you get anything else is up to the folks viewing it.